# Can I make the WebDrivers as global variables in Java

Tags: java, selenium

I want to create a class where I set all the common actions of the WebDrivers such as: waitExplicit, findElement, click. But if I create a method then I have to create the WebDriver and WebDriverWait over and over on each method of the class, I already tried having a class for the Drivers, but when I call the methods, they just create instances over and over, so multiple windows open, I tried this way, but still cannot get to it:

```
public class AutomationActions{
    
    static LoadProperties prop = new LoadProperties(); //This class has the System.setProperty for the driver
    prop.getSysProp(); //***This is the issue, how can I solve this?****
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); //this will not work without the one above working
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);//this will not work without the one above working

    public void waitForPageToLoad() throws Exception {
        ExpectedCondition<Boolean> pageLoadCondition = new
                ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
                    public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                        return ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
                    }
                };
//        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30); // I want to avoid having to set this in every method
        wait.until(pageLoadCondition); //this is supposed to replace the line of code above
        
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really work on Java much any more, I've written our framework in C# but I put together some quick classes in Java to show you how I set things up. I use page object model and I recommend you do too so I've written this example using page object model. I've written a simple test that uses Dave Haeffner's (one of the Selenium contributors) demo site, http://the-internet.herokuapp.com.

The basic concepts are:

1. There is a class `BaseTest` that holds things that correspond to tests, e.g. setting up the driver at the start of the test, quitting the driver at the end of the test, etc. All of your tests will inherit from `BaseTest`
2. There is a class `BasePage` that holds things that correspond to generic methods for finding elements, clicking on elements, etc. Each of your tests inherit from `BasePage`. (This is what I think the main part of your question is asking about).
3. To follow the page object model, each page (or part of a page) is its own class and holds all locators and actions done on that page. For example, a simple login page would have the locators for username, password, and the login button. It would also hold a method `Login()` that takes a `String` username and a `String` password, enters those in the appropriate fields and clicks the Login button.
4. The final class of this example is a sample test aptly named `SampleTest`.
5. You shouldn't have any `FindElements()` or related calls in your tests, all those should be in the appropriate page object.
6. This is using TestNG as the unit test library. Use it or JUnit, your preference but if you use JUnit, you will need to change the asserts and the annotations.

Under 'src', I create a folder for page objects, 'PageObjects', and a folder for tests, 'Tests'. Here's what the files look like on disk.

```
\src  
  \PageObjects
    BasePage.java
    DropdownListPage.java
  \Tests
    BaseTest.java
    SampleTest.java
```

BasePage.java

```
package PageObjects;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class BasePage
{
    private WebDriver driver;

    private final int shortWait = 10;

    public BasePage(WebDriver _driver)
    {
        driver = _driver;
    }

    public void ClickElement(By locator)
    {
        new WebDriverWait(driver, shortWait).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator)).click();
    }

    public WebElement FindElement(By locator)
    {
        return new WebDriverWait(driver, shortWait).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(locator));
    }

    // add more methods
}
```

DropdownListPage.java

```
package PageObjects;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class DropdownListPage extends BasePage
{
    private final By dropdownListLocator = By.id("dropdown");

    public DropdownListPage(WebDriver _driver)
    {
        super(_driver);
    }

    public String GetSelectedOption()
    {
        return new Select(FindElement(dropdownListLocator)).getFirstSelectedOption().getText();
    }

    public void SelectOptionByIndex(int index)
    {
        new Select(FindElement(dropdownListLocator)).selectByIndex(index);
    }
}
```

BaseTest.java

```
package Tests;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

public class BaseTest
{
    public WebDriver driver;

    public WebDriver GetChromeDriver()
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Path\\To\\Chrome\\Driver\\chromedriver.exe");

        return new ChromeDriver();
    }

    @BeforeTest
    public void Setup()
    {
        driver = GetChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/dropdown");
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void Teardown()
    {
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

SampleTest.java

```
package Tests;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import PageObjects.DropdownListPage;

public class SampleTest extends BaseTest
{
    @Test
    public void SampleTestCase()
    {
        DropdownListPage dropdownListPage = new DropdownListPage(driver);
        dropdownListPage.SelectOptionByIndex(1);
        Assert.assertEquals(dropdownListPage.GetSelectedOption(), "Option 1", "Verify first option was selected");
    }
}
```

You will need to create a project that contains Selenium for Java and TestNG. Download them and put them on your build path. Create the folder structure as described above and create each of these classes and copy/paste the contents into them. Now all you need to do is run SampleTest as a TestNG Test and it should go.

The test creates a new Chromedriver instance, navigates to the sample page, selects the first option in the dropdown, asserts that the dropdown text is correct, and then quits the driver.

That should get you started. There's a lot of info crammed into the above wall of text, let me know if you have some questions.

Comment: This looks amazing, I'm sorry I'm just starting on automation and this structure is kinda scary, one question  (I know I can look it up, but now that you have set all of this I wanna take the opportunity ),the line @beforeTest, is executed automatically somehow? I dont see where I should call it if it is not ran by itself.

Comment: Also, is it ok to create a new instance everytime on every method like int the class: "BasePage", I was trying to avoid that thinking it would be better? (for the WebDriverWait)

Comment: Yeah... it took me a while to get to this point so I can understand how it looks overwhelming. There's several things at work here... inheritance, TestNG, page object model, etc. Try it and see how it goes. Then once you have it working, start peeling apart the layers, google what you don't understand, etc. and you'll get there.

Comment: Yes, @BeforeTest is a [TestNG annotation](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations). It gets run automatically at a certain point. There are a lot of other annotations (see the link above) and it lists what they are and when they run. Taking advantage of them makes things a lot easier.

Comment: I generally use `WebDriverWait` when needed. I don't have a single instance that I reuse. The exception to that is if I need a couple waits inside a single method, I create a single instance and use it twice, etc. There's no delay in creating a new instance so there's little gained by creating a single instance and reusing it. If you hope to build a framework that runs tests in parallel, you have to be very careful about how and when you create instances like that where they can be used across threads and cause issues.

Comment: makes sense, one last question, I;ve been reading about those annotations, but what if I dont wanna test anything, and just want to automate a tedious process for myself, like removing some flags on some consumers, or clear some data, is it okay to use those annotations, or do I have to go back to use the main method? what could be used in that case?

Comment: Using the annotations, TestNG, page object model, etc. might be overkill for what you are planning now but it will make your life easier in the long run. If all you wanted to do was write one script and you were going to be done, I wouldn't bother with all of this. But... I don't think you would have asked this question if that was your goal. I took this question to mean you were looking for ways to improve your code, use best practices, etc. and that's why I wrote my answer the way I did.

Comment: Think of it this way... if all you want to write is one script, then do it the simplest way possible and move on. But what if you want to write a second script, then what? You could copy the first and adapt it to the new scenario. But what about a third and so on. Then what if you have a handful of tedious tasks you have automated and want to run them all at the same time or trigger them on a regular basis? Once you get into this territory, treating each script as a test becomes so much easier with TestNG, page object model, etc. It's all about making the next script easier to write and run.

Comment: Yes exactly, I mean I have several scripts, that would be just the same action and only that action, but as you said I do want to improve my code and apply best practices, even if that were to be overdone, it's fine, so the best way would still be to use the annotations, right? because as you said, I might want and I will add more actions or even add my previous scripts to this one.

Comment: You can use any of the annotations that you want. My guess is that the ones that I have in there now, `@BeforeTest`, `@AfterTest`, and `@Test`, will be enough, at least for now if not forever. Those are the only ones that I use in my frameworks.

Comment: That's a great start for me, thank you very much @JeffC I really appreciated